# Skip output of mysql query if user is blocked

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:  `question` and `block_user`

I use following query to fetch question which are active:

```
SELECT 
    tq.question_id,tq.info,tq.owner_id
FROM
    question as tq
     ..... Other Join .......
     ..... Other Join .......
where
    tq.is_active = '1'
```

`block_user` table contain these fields: `id,owner_id,question_id,block_user_id`

now if quesNown owner blocked some user, then those user not able to see question in which they are blocked.

exa:

suppose table `question` contain following data:

> `question_id`       `owner_id`       `info`
>
> 1  .......................              1  ................             Hello
> 2  .......................              1  ................             Hi
> 3  .......................              1  ................             Welcome
> 4  .......................              1      .................        Demo
> 5  .......................              1  ................             Stack Over flow

suppose table `block_user` contain following data:

> `id`    `owner_id`      `question_id`      `block_user_id`
>
> 1......        1.................               2......................                    2
> 2......        1.................               4.......................                   2

so, I am trying to do is if user 2 is tring to fetch question, then he is able to see question_id : `1,3,5`
He is not able to see question_id : `2,4` , because in this question he is blocked.

I use following but it is not working:

```
SELECT 
    tq.question_id,tq.info,tq.owner_id
FROM
    question as tq
        join
    block_user as tbu ON tq.user_id not in (tbu.user_id)
    and tq.question_id not in (tbu.question_id)
    and '2' not in (tbu.block_user_id)
     ..... Other Join .......
     ..... Other Join .......
where
    tq.is_active = '1'
```

So how to achive this in one query?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: feel free to change title of question.I am not able to find suitable one.

Comment: Just a little heads up, is the column `owner_id` in the table `block_user` really necessary? That seems like (dangerous) redundancy to me, unless question IDs are only unique in pair with the owner ID (which I would not recommend).

Comment: you are right, it is not necessary for this case, but It is useful when the owner tries to see a list of blocked users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I usually do this kind of query. I prefer to to a `LEFT JOIN` and discard those rows which match. Also you can use a subquery, but this usually obtain a faster result.

```
SELECT 
    tq.question_id,tq.info,tq.owner_id
FROM question as tq
    LEFT JOIN block_user as bu 
         ON tq.question_id = bu.question_id AND bu.block_user_id = '2'
     ..... Other Join .......
     ..... Other Join .......
WHERE tq.is_active = '1'
  AND bu.question_id IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks for answer. your query is working after changing `LEFT join block_user as bu ON bu.question_id =tq.question_id and bu.block_user_id = '2' where tq.is_active = '1' AND bu.question_id IS NULL`

Comment: I just realized that I made a mistake, I'm fixing my answer

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT 
    tq.question_id,tq.info,tq.owner_id
FROM
    question as tq
where
    tq.is_active = '1'
    and
    tq.question_id not in (SELECT bu.question_id from block_user bu where bu.block_user_id = {YOUR USER ID})
```